# Mongo findAndModify returns null

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query, mocha.js

Following.follow = function(id1, id2, cb) {
      console.log(id1) // returns Matt
      console.log(id2) // returns Simone

```
  Following.collection.findAndModify({
      query: {
          ownerId: id1
      },
      update: {
          $addToSet: {
              followedBy: id2
          }
      },
      upsert: true,
      new: true
  }, function(err, result, lastErrorObject) {
      cb(err, result)
      console.log(result) // returns null
  })
}
```

I'm running tests with Mocha and my findAndModify functions will only return null. I read the documentation and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Upsert combined with true should make the document if it isn't found and new should return the modified object.

Comment: you're calling console.log after your cb...
What happens if you swap the last two lines? `console.log(result); cb(err, result);`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is wrong in a number of ways:

First of all the [`.findAndModify()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findAndModify) syntax here is not valid for any node.js driver, and you probably meant [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) instead:

```js
  Following.collection.findOneAndUpdate({
    { "ownerId": id1 }, 
    { "$addToSet": { "followedBy": id2 } },
    { 
      "upsert": true,
      "returnOriginal": false
    },
    function(err, result) {
      console.log(result);   // if you don't call before the callback it never gets called.
      cb(err, result);
    }
  );
```

Second case is that the `.collection` there implies that this is coming from "mongoose", so use the native method that mongoose has instead for [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

```js
  Following.findOneAndUpdate({
    { "ownerId": id1 }, 
    { "$addToSet": { "followedBy": id2 } },
    { 
      "upsert": true,
      "new": true
    },
    function(err, result) {
      console.log(result);   // if you don't call before the callback it never gets called.
      cb(err, result);
    }
  );
```

And that last is likely what you want if you are passing around strings that need to case to things like `ObjectId` and you are not handling that manually. Mongoose handles that. The native driver does not do that for you, as it has no "schema" to reference to work out the "type casting".

So use the methods that should be supported.